# How to exclude header when using Select-Object from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am using Get-ADUser on Powershell to retrieve a list of Title attribute then feed it to a file using Add-Content. The script iterates between multiple ADSearchBases hence the feed file is prepared before hand with the desired header. However, as the script runs for each ADSearchBase, multiple headers are also added in the feed file.

Do note that I will be extracting multiple properties down the line, the sample below is for just 1 property.

The resulting file will be fed to an application hence the formatting requirements.

```
$ADFilter = "objectCategory -eq 'Person'"

Set-Content -Path feedfile.txt -Value "sym"

$ADSearchBases = @("OU=test1,DC=ABC,DC=ABC","OU=test2,DC=DEF,DC=ABC")
foreach ($ADSearchBase in $ADSearchBases) {
    Get-ADUser -Server $DomainController -Credential $myCredentials -SearchBase $ADSearchBase -Filter $ADFilter -Properties 'Title' |
        Select-Object title |
        Add-Content feedfile.txt
}
```

Current result

```
sym  
title  
Employee  
Manager  
title  
Sales Clerk  
Cashier
```

Expected result

```
sym  
Employee  
Manager  
Sales Clerk  
Cashier
```

Comment: Because each of these `"OU=test1,DC=ABC,DC=ABC","OU=test2,DC=DEF,DC=ABC")` are individual datasets, not one. If you don't want that then you have tode for using customer objects or using row skipping.

Comment: You don't need that filter `objectCategory -eq 'Person'` because Get-ADUser will automatically return only user objects.

Comment: @Theo I get prompted for a Filter during execution

Comment: @Ruben_PH Sorry, forgot that. Added the filter in now

Comment: Hey, I did try to incorporate both your and Santiago's answer but it just doesn't fulfill my needs. Currently, I am still using the my answer as posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a better way to do this that comes around, here is what works for me.
I ended up feeding the result of Get-ADUser to a variable and loop thru that variable to skip the 1st value which is the unwanted header.

```
$ADFilter = "objectCategory -eq 'Person'"

Set-Content -Path feedfile.txt -Value "sym"

$ADSearchBases = @("OU=test1,DC=ABC,DC=ABC","OU=test2,DC=DEF,DC=ABC")
ForEach ($ADSearchBase in $ADSearchBases) {
    $ADTitles = Get-ADUser -Server $DomainController -Credential $myCredentials -SearchBase $ADSearchBase -Filter $ADFilter -Properties 'Title' |
        Select-Object title
    $i = 1
    ForEach ($ADTitle in $ADTitles){
        If($i -eq 1){
            $i++
            continue
        }
        Add-Content feedfile.txt -Value $ADPosition
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an improved solution to your problem. It's important to avoid [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.3) inside the loop to increase performance of your script.

If you want to get the [Property Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7.3#property-values) using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) you can use `-ExpandProperty`. i.e.:

```bash
Select-Object -ExpandProperty title
```

Or through [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) as demonstrated in this example:

```bash
$ADFilter = "objectCategory -eq 'Person'"
$ADSearchBases = @(
    "OU=test1,DC=ABC,DC=ABC"
    "OU=test2,DC=DEF,DC=ABC"
)

$hash = @{
    Server     = $DomainController
    Credential = $myCredentials
    Filter     = $ADFilter
    Properties = 'Title'
}

$result = foreach($searchBase in $ADSearchBases) {
    $hash.SearchBase = $searchBase
    (Get-ADUser @hash).title
}

Set-Content -Path feedfile.txt -Value "sym"
Add-Content -Path feedfile.txt -Value $result
```

Comment: Thanks. I have actually read about -ExpandProperty while researching for this problem. However, I will be extracting multiple attributes down the line and I read that -ExpandProperty is not good for multiple objects?

Comment: I like your formatting by the way. Does the values for $ADSearchBases does not have a comma in between them? $ADSearchBases = @(
    "OU=test1,DC=ABC,DC=ABC",
    "OU=test2,DC=DEF,DC=ABC"

Comment: @Ruben_PH I don't understand why you want to add the header to a text file and then add the values, why not create an object with the headers you want and then export? That can easily be done with a `pscustomobject` and yes, `-ExpandProperty` is no good for multiple properties.

Comment: @Ruben_PH What I personally do when I need to extract AD data is export to a CSV file or Excel file, txt is not the greatest output formats for AD Objects. Regarding your question for `$ADSearchBases`, elements of an array in PowerShell can be separated by commas or a new line if using the [**array subexpression operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#array-subexpression-operator--) `@( ... )`

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you don't need the filter on ObjectCategory with Get-ADUser.
This should do what you need

```
Set-Content -Path feedfile.txt -Value "sym"

$ADSearchBases = "OU=test1,DC=ABC,DC=ABC","OU=test2,DC=DEF,DC=ABC"  # no need for @() to construct an array
$ADSearchBases | ForEach-Object {
    # inside here, the $_ automatic variable represents one of the SearchBases
    # get the users and return only their Title property as string
    (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server $DomainController -Credential $myCredentials -SearchBase $_ -Properties 'Title').Title
} | Add-Content -Path feedfile.txt
```